# Android BackGround service not works in Lollipop using start service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-intentservice, explicit-intent

I have an android app service for pushing notification which run in the background.
It invokes the intent using startService(); It works fine in pre-versions but it does not work on lollipop.  I am not aware of Why it is not works (Because service intents must be explicit in lollipop) but when i" trying to make it explecit background service not works.How to resolve it.

Here is part of working code to invoke service:

MainActivity

```
   Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.START_SERVICE");
   this.startService(serviceIntent);
```

Manifest

```
 <service android:name=".MyService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.START_SERVICE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your packageName i think its work.

```
intent.setPackage(this.getPackageName());
```

Comment: not worked.............

Comment: You want to update your google libreries to newer version

Comment: it is app for push notification without gcm like things .but service not runninng continuously in background in lollipop but prelollipop it works.